# Calculating how long a form has been filled out in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, forms, time

So I have a form on my webpage and I want to implement a system which tells the user how long he filled out the form.

Is it possible to start a counter variable (timer) on JavaScript when the user starts filling out any textfield on the form, then send this counter data after he presses the submit button? I'd like to send this as a POST argument to another page, which would tell the user how long he filled out the previous page's form.

Comment: Yep. That's possible.

Comment: could you tell me how? :3

Comment: I would put a time stamp at the load of the page, then another time stamp at the submission of the time stamp, then subtract the larger time stamp from the shorter time stamp.  Look into: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.time.php

Comment: Its better to do with JavaScript or jQuery

Comment: Its better for the user. But it could be easily altered. That's why its called _client-side_ @DipuRaj

Comment: @IGotRoot ooh okay I get how I would do it that way. But how will I set the first timestamp only when the user starts editing a textfield?

Comment: @DipuRaj how would I do it with JavaScript? I'm not really after security or anything, so it's okay if it can be altered by people who knows how to mess with JavaScript.

Comment: for exactly when the user starts pressing keys on the keyboard, you would use javascript, not php, unless you're using ajax to pass data to the server as they enter it, so that it can be saved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you could do something like this (http://jsfiddle.net/bNNwz/5/)

```
var formInitializationTime;

$('form input').bind('keypress change click', function () {
    if (!formInitializationTime) formInitializationTime = new Date();
});

$('form').bind('submit', function () {
    document.querySelector('input.duration').value = new Date() - formInitializationTime;
});
```

Comment: I don't like writing code out for people, unless they're very close to the solution, and/or want to write it more clearly for others to read.

Comment: thanks! this looks like a workable solution for me. I just have to modify some bits other than that it works just as I wanted. :D

Comment: @IGotRoot Seemed simple enough. But a newbie may not know how to modify form values upon submission.

Comment: @ChadSciraa nooblet should ask a professor if they're just learning how to code.  there are also plenty of videos online for people to learn how to code from.  There is plenty of help in these videos: https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+code+a+javascript+timer&oq=how+to+code+a+javascript+timer&aqs=chrome..69i57j0.11878j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8#q=how+to+code+a+javascript+timer&tbm=vid

Comment: @IGotRoot sorry haha, I learn languages by myself and I don't really have to time to skim through several lengthy videos just to look for solution to this specific problem, so I though stackoverflow was the best way to get it done.

Comment: you take the principles from the video, and make it your own solution in cases like that.